# Mailcore: Can't delete from Spam folder

Tags: ios, mailcore2

I have delete successfully functioning in my iOS app. I've tried it in several folders and the message is removed from the app and server. However when I delete a message in the Spam folder in the app it doesn't get deleted from the Spam folder on the server (Gmail).

To delete I am using the `storeFlagsOperationWithFolder` and setting the delete flag.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to run the `expungeOperation:` after changing the flag. This is necessary in Gmails Spam and Trash folders.